# How to validate data with elasticsearch while indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I need to prevent certain fields which have values like "null" (null as a string) and `""`(empty string) from getting indexed in Elasticsearch i.e. I should be able to fetch the document which doesn't contain those fields in _source field.

Are there any settings that are required in mappings while indexing, like using an custom analyzer on a field?

P.S:- I am using elasticsearch 7.6.1

I tried below answer and this is how it didn't work -

```
{  "settings": {
"number_of_shards": "5",
"analysis": {
  "normalizer": {
    "my_normalizer": {
      "char_filter": [
        {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "null =>",
            "\"\"\" =>"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        "uppercase"
      ],
      "type": "custom"
    }
  }
},
"number_of_replicas": "1"}}
```

Response error - only value lists are allowed in serialized settings

While even when I tried as below settings I didn't get expected outcome:

```
{  "settings": {
"number_of_shards": "5",
"analysis": {
  "char_filter": {
    "my_filter": {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "null =>",
        "\"\"\" =>"
      ]
    }
  },
  "normalizer": {
    "my_normalizer": {
      "char_filter": [
        "my_filter"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "uppercase"
      ],
      "type": "custom"
    }
  }
},
"number_of_replicas": "1"}}
```

request -
**GET** *indexname/_analyze*

```
{"normalizer":"my_normalizer","text":"null"}
```

response -

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "",
        "start_offset": 4,
        "end_offset": 4,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    }
]
```

}

expected response -

```
{
"tokens": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [mapping char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html#analysis-mapping-charfilter) in your analyzer definition, you can achieve it, below is the working example.

**Analyze API**

```
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "char_filter": [
    {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "null =>",
        "\"\"\" =>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "text": "null" or "" --> note this
}
```

**And returned token**

```
{
    "tokens": []
}
```

Comment: Likely this is student homework and no attempts taken. Please remove answer before user sees solution. EoR.

Comment: This didnt help

Comment: @Trupti wow, you simply saying didn't help, I am not supposed to answer as per other users and community closed your question, and you are not bothering to explain your question and why my solution didn't work :)

Comment: @Trupti please understand its community and you need to follow certain guidelines when seeking help.

Comment: @Trupti I see you updated the question, but wondering why you are making it complicated, why can't you simply use the setting which I provided in my answer, which doesn't use any normalized and other extra things you added.

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja I have updated details in question. Please let me know if that helps

Comment: @Trupti, yes I see and already left a comment, can you reply to it??

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja I have used settings that you provided, but that didnt work. I have provided settings that I did as per your suggestion , and response also. And I need normalizer in my index serving different purpose.

Comment: @Trupti, I tried and with your added things aka normalizer it won't work, you need to use the settings as it is provided in my answer to make it work

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja, No didnt find any solution here